# No muestra acentos y ñ's en mi proyecto PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy usando una conexion a MySQL PDO, en MySQL si me muestra los acentos (') y las ñ de manera correcta, pero al momento de mostrarlo en PHP no lo hace. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2):

puedes utilizar estas funciones...

```
       utf8_decode("string") 
       utf8_encode("string")
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso es debido a la codificación. Puedes utilizar:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

al inicio de tu fichero PHP.

Además, puedes codificar tu HTML poniendo la siguiente etiqueta en tu cabecera:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Por último, dependiendo en que tipo de codificación esté tu base de datos podrías usar los métodos `utf8_encode` o `utf8_decode` en cada una de las variabes que quieras mostrar desde tu PHP.

Algo así:

```
utf8_encode($variable);
utf8_decode($variable);
```