# Error de tildación en base de datos SQL con PHP

Tags: php, html5, sql-server, utf-8

Buen día, tengo el siguiente problema:
No se muestran las tildes que han sido colocadas en la BD SQL, en el HTML he declarado el meta charset:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

En la BD si logro visualizar las palabras tildadas, pero en la web se muestran simbolos. Adjunto imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceré sus aportes

Comment: pregunta triplicada o más. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37721/no-muestra-acentos-y-%c3%b1s-en-mi-proyecto-php

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este Doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo lo mejor es que dentro del archivo php coloque el siguiente codigo

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

para que en en los headers de la petición te reconozca los caracteres como las tildes.

*No olvides aceptar la respuesta si fue de tu ayuda.*